# Repeating decimal : one the most standard form

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Is there consensus on representing rational numbers as finte/repeating decimals?
I mean, the unique, the most standard form.

Everyone would agree to the followings :

```
1/3 → 0.(3) (the most standard)  
1/3 → 0.(33) (acceptable but not the standard)  
1/3 → 0.3(3) (acceptable but not the standard)
```

But some rationals are really confusing (at least to me)

```
10/3 → 3.(3) (From general people's point of view)  
10/3 → (3) (From a mathematician's point of view)


12.312312312.... → 12.(312) (From general people's point of view)  
12.312312312.... → (12.3) (From a mathematician's point of view)
```

We can use overbar, dot or parenthesis to represent a repeating decimal.
But my question is not about these notations.
My question is about period.

Comment: I have never seen this usage in any of the forms you show. I doubt that there is a  standard  or a consensus.

Comment: I'm a mathematician, and I would write $12.312312312\dots=12.\dot31\dot2$ or $12.\overline{312}$.

Comment: I understand the thinking behind the expression $~\overline{12.3}.~$ However, I have never seen that type of expression and I suspect that many mathematicians would be unsure what the expression intends.  In contrast, no mathematician will be confused by the expression $~12.\overline{312}.$

Comment: Thank you, then the most standard method is to find the minimum period within the range that does not invade the integer part.